# Which is a better practice for a reset function?

Tags: c++, memory, reset

**Edit**: `MyClass` is just an example. The question is actually about how to reset part of the members of a class. In my real case, the class is more complicated, and `data` would be as long as a million. Also, I have copy/move c'tors and operators, which are omitted in my example.

I have a class

```
class MyClass{
     double *data;
     int data_length;         

     MyClass() : data(nullptr), data_length(0){}

     ~MyClass(){
         if(data != nullptr){
             delete[] data;
         }
     }
}
```

Now I want to add a new member function `reset()`.
Which of the following is a better practice?

(a)

```
MyClass::reset(double* in_data, int in_length){
    if(data != nullptr){
        delete[] data;
    }
    data = new double[in_length];
    memcpy(data, in_data, in_length * sizeof(double));
    data_length = in_length;
}
```

and

(b)

```
MyClass::reset(double* in_data, int in_length){
    if(data != nullptr){
        delete[] data;
    }
    data = in_data;
    data_length = in_length;
}
```

It seems that (a) is safer, but it is more time consuming, and the clients of (a) have to manually delete temp `in_data` after calling `reset()`. (b) is more efficient, but it takes a risk that the client may delete `in_data` outside.

Comment: Why do you want to "reset" an object? (Also, why no `std::<shared/unique>_ptr` ?)

Comment: In the first variant, you´re missing the allocation. Anyways, you´ve discovered the problem why move semantics were introduced. And what´s better depends on your use case.

Comment: `std::vector` looks like a better fit, but yeah, why roll your own memory management? This stuff exists in the standard library; you only have to use it, not reimplement it. (Side note: `delete nullptr;` does nothing, so there's no need to check for it)

Comment: @JBL just for example. If a class has multiple data pointers, and I want to change one of them. I'd like to reset it, instead of reconstruct the whole class.

Comment: What is the maximum size of `data` you're expecting? Modern computers are so fast that they can copy a large array easily, so maybe you should choose the safer solution?

Comment: If your class MyClass is a resource class, write it as simple as possible with all the regular members.  Then you would use instances of MyClass instead of double pointers risk-free. If this is not an exercise use std::vector.

Comment: Before you implement a `reset()` function, how about implementing the copy/move constructor/assignment-operators? Or use `std::vector`.

Comment: If you provide the function reset to the user by e.g. dll file then in (b) example memory might be freed by another runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a data member:

```
std::vector<double> data;
```

Then:

```
void reset(std::vector<double>&& new_data) { data = std::move(new_data); }
void reset(const std::vector<double>& new_data) { data = new_data; }
```

The first overload above will move data from an expiring `vector<>` if implicitly allowed or you explicitly grant permission in the calling code using `std::move()`, otherwise the second overload will copy:

```
myClass.reset(get_new_data_vector());  // moves returned vector

std::vector x = { ... };
myClass.reset(x); // do a full "deep" copy
myClass.reset(std::move(x));  // explicitly allow move from named local var
```

If you have other data collections, you can do something similar for each - each can be updated efficiently and independently.

Comment: If the size of the data is long enough, it might be worth splitting `reset` into two overloads, taking lvalue- and rvalue-references respectively.

Comment: The optimizer cannot always change your code, you are asking for specific operations and those will be carried out. The issue would be if the internal buffer is already large enough to hold the new value and the caller is using an lvalue (i.e. they still want the values after the call to `reset`). The data could be copied in place, but the use of the by-value argument forces an allocation, copying the elements and the destruction of the old elements and release of the old buffer [the type being `double` means that destruction is no-op, but bear with me], where a single `memcpy` would work

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm sold - thanks for walking me through it.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to copy the data and not depend on outside world for such stuff, especially when you have a destructor which deletes memory the class did not allocate.

Comment: "deleting memory they did not allocate".... that is what destructors are good for, isn't it? Typically memory is allocated in constructor (or elsewhere) and rarely in a destructor.

Comment: @tobi303 i don't get your point. And i haven't mentioned anything about allocating memory in a destructor. Oh i see, in "memory it did not allocate" "it" stands for  the class. So what i tried to point out is that in case b) of OP, MyClass frees memory it did not allocate, which to me is a code smell.